# Full deep checking client IP address using PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

Over the years I create this algorithm for checking client IP address in "deep mode". Here is also included Cloudflare and proxy etc.

In that script i put all possible $_SERVER variables in array what may contain client IP and after in loop I check and validate first accurate IP address.

Here is my list:

```
$findIP=array(
        'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP',
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'REMOTE_ADDR',
        'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'CLIENT_IP',
        'FORWARDED',
        'X_FORWARDED',
        'FORWARDED_FOR',
        'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'VIA',
        'HTTP_VIA',
        'BAN_CHECK_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    );
```

**QUESTION: Is this order OK and do I put something unuseful and do you know something more what I need to add?**

I try to cover all possibilities and be most accurate.

My current code work perfect but sometimes Cloudflare send wrong data and also mobile devices made me some problems and some proxy servers.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you using the IP for?

Comment: I don't think your codes work for anonymous proxy. The user actual IP address is not part of server variables.

Comment: @Dagon I use Ip to get geodata from ip2location. I have a lot of trouble before to get right IP and I come with this like "ideal" solution but I find that I have sometimes a problems.

Comment: @MichaelC. true, but is there a way to get the most accurate IP? HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR give me sometimes 2 or 3 IP address and I normaly choose the last one. What can be done here?

Comment: if you need it accurate you should ask the user vi the html5 Geolocation api, not use the IP (which will ever be that reliable)

Comment: @Dagon good point. Problem with this is also that I need to use same IP and geodata in PHP because I pull some other content based on city, regio and state. All to proccess via AJAX then?